# Displaying Authenticated User Using Laravel Sanctum Api

Tags: php, laravel, bearer-token, laravel-sanctum

I want to display the data of the authenticated user and also produce a status code and a status message when the user is not authenticated. I am using Laravel API and Sanctum and this is what I have tried:

```
public function me(Request $request){    
    
    $user = $request->user();

    if($user)
    {
    return response()->json([
        'status'=>200,
        'user'=>$user
    ]);
    
} else {
    return response()->json([
        'status'=>401,
        'message'=>'No access'
    ]);
}

}
```

Problem is, it displays the status 200 when authenticated and does not display the status 401 code when not. It only displays the default Sanctum

```
{
"message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

There is also a bearer token involved in the authentication.
Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

If you confirmed that the token already involved in Authorization header, maybe you need to check some of this step:

You need to verify that in your User model already add **HasApiTokens** from package **Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens**.

After that, you can check the router middleware. You can use middleware **auth:sanctum** for protected endpoint. If you were using middleware ability, maybe you can check it too.

Go to config/cors.php, enable **supports_credentials** to true.

If you tried it before using your Frontend apps, have you try it with postman ?